# How are double mappings indexed?

Tags: solidity

**Spec**:

1. Wallets have sums paid to them for different tokens.

**Design**

1. Wallet address maps to totalpaid by token.

**Implementation**

1. Two mappings, one for wallet address, one for a token label (designed to be an integer based on a second struct)

**Error**

1. Integer constant expected

This line fails -

```
 uint _TotalPaid = PaymentDetail[_TokenIndex][_Wallet].TotalPaid;
```

Has anyone any ideas about how to solve this error?

Here is the code -

```
    struct PaymentDetail {
        uint TotalPaid;
    }

    mapping (bytes32 => mapping (uint => PaymentDetail[]) ) public PaymentDetails; 

    function addPaymentDetail (bytes32 _Wallet, uint _TokenIndex, uint _Payment) public {
        uint _TotalPaid = PaymentDetail[_TokenIndex][_Wallet].TotalPaid;
        _TotalPaid=_TotalPaid+_Payment;
        PaymentDetail[_Wallet][_TokenIndex].TotalPaid=_TotalPaid;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#mappings) . Mapping types are declared as `mapping(_KeyType => _ValueType)`. Here `_KeyType` can be almost any type except for a mapping, a **`dynamically sized array`**, a contract, an enum and a struct. `_ValueType` can actually be any type, including mappings. 
It not possible directly make an array of struct as value type. But it is possible for other data types, like :

```
 mapping (bytes32 => mapping (uint => arrayofdata[index_of_array]) ) public PaymentDetails;
```

Here I changed the code as solidity support for struct as value type in mapping.

```
struct PaymentDetail {  
        uint TotalPaid;  
        }

    mapping (bytes32 => mapping (uint => PaymentDetail) ) public PaymentDetails; 

    function addPaymentDetail (bytes32 _Wallet, uint _TokenIndex, uint _Payment) public {
        uint _TotalPaid = PaymentDetails[_Wallet][_TokenIndex].TotalPaid;
        _TotalPaid=_TotalPaid+_Payment;
        PaymentDetails[_Wallet][_TokenIndex].TotalPaid=_TotalPaid;
    }
```

Comment: I had tried the order as you state, but I missed for plural part of the PaymentDetails. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the mapping with name `PaymentDetails` but you are trying to access the contents of struct type `PaymentDetail`, which does not make sense. I bet that's a typo. Also, as Ha ĐANG noted, you are accessing the mapping in a wrong way.

Change

`uint _TotalPaid = PaymentDetail[_TokenIndex][_Wallet].TotalPaid;`

to

`uint _TotalPaid = PaymentDetails[_Wallet][_TokenIndex].TotalPaid;`

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong position for the keys of the mapping. It should be as below to matching with you declaration

```
uint _TotalPaid = PaymentDetails[_Wallet][_TokenIndex].TotalPaid;
```

Further, you'd better to use `address` for wallet, should not use `bytes32` for the address/wallet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83150/discussion-on-answer-by-ha-dang-how-are-double-mappings-indexed).